# ADF Validation-Salary should not be greater than manager salary in ADF

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf

Emp table have attributes:

```
 Empno,
 Ename,
 ManagerId,
 Salary.
```

How to add validation for salary field being less than manager salary field??
Note:No separate table for manager

Comment: Do you want it problematically or decoratively?

Comment: Decoratively would be fine..I wanted to set validation through UI on EO..Not via editing Java class